# Dictionary key, value pairs of a cell to columns whose name is key and row is value in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I found it very hard to frame the question using the right words.. But I hope I've done a good job..

Here is an example that I artificially created so you can reproduce it in your console.

```
example = pd.DataFrame([['a', [{'a1': 1,
        'a2': {'amount': 20, 'currency': 'USD'}, 'a3': 57},
       {'a1': 4,
        'a2': {'amount': 50, 'currency': 'USD'}},
       {'a1': 7,
        'a2': {'amount': 80, 'currency': 'USD'}}], 10, 11], 

                        ['b', [{'a1': 13,
        'a2': {'amount': 140, 'currency': 'USD'}},
       {'a1': 2,
        'a2': {'amount': 50, 'currency': 'USD'}},
       {'a1': 3,
        'a2': {'amount': 90, 'currency': 'USD'}}], 16, 17], 

                        ['c', [{'a1': 8,
        'a2': {'amount': 75, 'currency': 'USD'}},
       {'a1': 9,
        'a2': {'amount': 90, 'currency': 'USD'}, 'a3': 98},
       {'a1': 6,
        'a2': {'amount': 10, 'currency': 'USD'}}], 11, 12]])

example.columns = ['column1', 'column2', 'column3', 'column4']
print(example)
```

The DataFrame `example`'s second column is a list of nest dictionary like structure.

```
print(example.loc[[0], ["column2"]].values.tolist())

[[[{'a1': 1, 'a2': {'amount': 20, 'currency': 'USD'}, 'a3': 57},
   {'a1': 4, 'a2': {'amount': 50, 'currency': 'USD'}},
   {'a1': 7, 'a2': {'amount': 80, 'currency': 'USD'}}]]]
```

This is row `0`, column named `column2` that I've printed using `loc`.

The `print(exampleSolution)` statement should give you the Pandas DataFrame I'm looking to get.

```
exampleSolution = pd.DataFrame([['a', 1, 20, 'USD', 57, 10, 11], ['a', 4, 50, 'USD', None, 10, 11], 
                                ['a', 7, 80, 'USD', None, 10, 11], ['b', 13, 140, 'USD', None, 16, 17], 
                                ['b', 2, 50, 'USD', None, 16, 17], ['b', 3, 90, 'USD', None, 16, 17], 
                                ['c', 8, 75, 'USD', None, 11, 12], ['c', 9, 90, 'USD', 98, 11, 12], 
                                ['c', 6, 10, 'USD', None, 11, 12]])

exampleSolution.columns = ['column1', 'a1', 'amount', 'currency', 'a3', 'column3', 'column4']
print(exampleSolution)
```

Basically, I want the dictionary inside `column2` to be unpacked for each row, I want the dictionary key to be an additional column name, and the value in the row to be the dictionary value corresponding to that key. In case there are certain keys, value pairs for other rows (like in my example we see the first row `0` that I've used `loc` to print out having this key `a3` while the same row `0` does not have an `a3` in the second and third item of its nested dictionary! And similarly, the row `2` also has a key `a3` in the second item of its nested dictionary. Similarly **I want the solution to be robust to cases were there may be a particular key, value pair in the nested dictionary that is NEVER seen in any other row!** There could be an `a4` within the nested dictionary of `column2` for a particular row, and an `a5` for another row, I want those additional column to exist in the resulting DataFrame regardless; with a `None` or a `NaN`! Also, the second column as you may have seen by now has a key `a2`, within which there is a nested (key, value) pair which I want as separate columns `amount`, `currency` key, value pair.

```
    column1  a1  amount currency    a3  column3  column4
0       a    1      20      USD  57.0       10       11
1       a    4      50      USD   NaN       10       11
2       a    7      80      USD   NaN       10       11
3       b   13     140      USD   NaN       16       17
4       b    2      50      USD   NaN       16       17
5       b    3      90      USD   NaN       16       17
6       c    8      75      USD   NaN       11       12
7       c    9      90      USD  98.0       11       12
8       c    6      10      USD   NaN       11       12
```

What have I done so far?

I'm ashamed to say that I don't know where to start..

The above example is a MUCH SMALLER version of a Pandas DataFrame that I derived from a JSON file (300 MB). I initially, unnecessarily spent LOTS of time creating the nested dictionary structure and then unzipping the convoluted nested dictionary only to find that the command to create a DataFrame from JSON was `pd.read_json()`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize    

rows = list(example.index)    

mainDf = pd.DataFrame()
for index in rows:
    listing = example.at[index, "column2"]

    df = pd.DataFrame()    


    for i in listing:


        l = (json_normalize(i))

        df = df.append(l)

    otherCols = list(example.columns)
    otherCols.remove('column2')

    for col in otherCols:
        #print(example.loc[[index], [col]])

        df[col] = example.at[index, col]

    mainDf = mainDf.append(df)


print(mainDF)
```